# Looking for jQuery image slider that is truly "circular"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, carousel

What I'm looking for is a jQuery image slider that shows one image at a time, but on either side, it has a small portion of the **last** image to the left, as well as a small portion of the **second image** to the right of that first image. The [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home) has a slider I'm looking to recreate (this chooses a starting slide at random; I don't need this).

Right now I'm just using [jQuery Carousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) to show one image at a time, and I can't really figure out a way to make it like the Chrome web store. If anyone has a plugin they've used, or know how to extend the current one, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jCarousel has [a major known bug](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/issues/search?&q=circular) with it's circular option.  Most of the carousels including jCarousel use cloning to achieve the circular effect and sometimes the way it's done adds other issues.

Here's a tutorial on how to write your own which is simple circular carousel and uses no cloning...

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-infinite-carousel-with-nice-features/

Demo...

http://web.enavu.com/demos/carousel_revisited/

Comment: Awesome method o.ob only problem is when you have four items hence the cloning in other examples...

Comment: @Joseph, I get what you're saying.  However, you don't have to reveal any specified number.  If you only have four items, simply reveal three and again you won't need cloning.

Comment: I know.  All I'm saying is that for these people developing plugins that are intended to be versatile to many scenarios probably use cloning to idiot proof their code.  I personally prefer the `$("#slider :last").insertBefore("#slider :first")` method and have used it many times.

Comment: @Joseph, I understand.  The other problem I've had with the cloning is when used in conjunction with a lightbox like prettyPhoto.  It gets very confused by the cloned items when clicking next/previous.